# Detect running competition winner`s starting number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a task in in excel and I can`t think of the solution right now.
So I have a spreadsheet with running competition results: [The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi5q2.png)

So I need to detect which is the fastest runner that has ran all 3 laps (the winner) and detect the number(Nr) of the winner.

The F column is for calculations if needed

So I detected who had ran all 3 laps with this formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(C2:E2)>2;SUM(C2:E2);"DNF")
```

Then I determined who is the winner by running a min formula:

```
=MIN(F2:F79)
```

Now I need to detect what number the winner has, So it will be in the A column and in the same row where the row where =MIN(F2:F79) result is.

This is an task so manually finding it won`t work this time.

It is probably a really simple solution but I can`t think of it right now so it would be really nice if somebody could help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this utilizing **Index - Match**.

The formula you would place in cell *H2* would be as follows:

```
=Index($A$2:$F$79,MATCH($G$2,$F$2:$F$79,0),1)
```

What this does is it looks at the whole table and takes the Winner total time (*cell G2*) and matches it with the corresponding value in *Column F*, and then returns the first column (*Column A*).